# Visualization of Gauss Bonnet geometric objects

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Where can we get to see some *individual* surface/line combinations in isometry

visualizations with constant $ \int k_g ds $  (say total tangential rotation) ? Or

with constant integral curvature $\int\int K dA $ ? ( say on closed contours).

There is sufficiently good comprehension about constant $ K$ surfaces or constant

$k_g$ lines on them. Spherical images or Gauss map is just one aspect.

First comes to mind of any student perusing surfaces is a desire to graphically see

these objects *separately* before they were put together in the GB Theorem, but is

easily cowed down with the appearance of plethora of  $\int$ signs and their as yet

unrevealed significances etc., quickly resigns to their reality of their final

symbolic theorem structure...Mathematical colossus Gauss set them into a symbolically

structured elegant equation. Lagrange was eloquent ..no need for imagery,even in

derivations.

Just my humble two cents.

EDIT:

The second question I want to ask:

The tangential rotation and solid angle above are married together, so to say, to lose

or gain a part of their individual isometric character to be together equal to a

topological invariant $ 2 \pi ( 1- \chi)$. That it is so, is well established.

But, what is the *compensatory topological content U*  that changes in this union,

i.e., in a simply connected patch when

$ (\int k_g ds  +U) $ +  $(\int\int K dA  - U )$ = $ 2 \pi$ ?

Please give me a couple of days to add more content to my thoughts, before the moderators

view its on/off topic relevance.Thanks.

Comment: What about the area of a spherical triangle?

Comment: In the above, mentioned that there is adequate understanding about cases with constant K and kg.